# normal map water ripples effect on unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, shader

I'm currently creating a game where there is a lot of water. The player plays a boat and sails on water.

The game will be available on mobile, so the graphics are quite simple (not really expensive), but i want to add 2d ripples effect on the water like this :

http://mattatz.github.io/unity/lbm-fluid-simulation/

So i search on internet, and a lot of solution exist. I found one very interesting because it matchs what i'm looking for.

It's a unity package available at this address:

http://1darray.com/blog/2011/11/27/2d-waterfluid-fx/

i play with it but i would like to use a collider mesh instead of mousebutton.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The magic here is happening in the shaders - which you probably don't need to touch for now. Start by looking at how they're used in LBM.cs, and try to adapt that script to your needs. At the present stage in your development it's unlikely people on Stack Overflow can help you with that - questions here need to have very clearly defined programming problems (often with a current coding attempt). Once you've worked with the script a while, if you can't overcome a particular problem, then write up a question here explaining what it is and how you've tried to solve it.